# Center one image within another in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to center one image within another in Swift using the storyboard.  I aligned Center X and Center Y, but the image is definitely offset.  What am I doing wrong?

The frame is correctly placed, but the cat is offset.  (The blue is for development only and will be made transparent once it's positioned.)

Cat attributes:
[image: cat attributes]

Frame attributes:
[image: frame attributes]

Storyboard: [image: storyboard]

Preview: [image: preview]

Comment: I've changed the tags and removed "Swift" as the question and the answer is independent of the programming language. It would be the same with Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In this image you can see the ‘Align Center x’ Equals `56`  You will need to set this value to `0`. Same for the ‘Align Center y’.

The value behind the Equals defines an offset.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense.  I should have seen that.  Any idea where those numbers would have come from?  I'm not near my code now, but I'll be sure to accept your answer as soon as I can test it.

Comment: If you center the image, using constraints, it will take the current offset and apply that as the offset that you want, I reckon you didn’t center the image in your storyboard before you centered the image using constraints?

Comment: That is correct--that explains many of the problems I've been having!  Thanks!